# What is the alternative of the activex?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, activex

I have third party app.. And I need some data from it..

That app allow to get data with activex and jquery.. It works fine..

But I want to use this data without activex.. Maybe with Xml??

Comment: This will depend on what exactly is the ActiveX doing. Also the only resemblance between XML and ActiveX is the first and last letter, a.k.a. they have absolutely nothing in common.

Comment: actually i dont know how can i ask my question..

There is third party windows app.. And I need data from third party app.. (Data is changing instantly..) So I want to see datas on my web page.. I can see datas with activex but It is not enough because my client firstly has to install activex.. I dont want them to install it..

So Xml just a thought.. Maybe firstly I can get data with activex than I would transfer data to Xml.. So I can use datas which way I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two things in mind for such type of communication: ActiveX and Java applet. But in both cases the end used has to install something.

You can do nothing with desktop app with JavaScript only due to security reasons.